# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. date not accepting

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I get a stored procedure execution error while passing the date parameters

```
create procedure emp_leave_from_to
    @emp_code int,
    @leave_from_date date ,
    @leave_to_date date
as
begin 
    create table #employee_leave
    (
         emp_code varchar (100),
         emp_name varchar (100),
         emp_department varchar(50),
         leave_from_date date
    )

    insert into #employee_leave (emp_code, leave_from_date)
        select employee_code, leave_from_date
        from emp_leave
        where leave_from_date between @leave_from_date and @leave_to_date

    update temp 
    set temp.emp_name = a.employee_name,
        temp.emp_department = a.dept
    from #employee_leave temp, employee a
    where a.employee_code = temp.emp_code
end 

exec emp_leave_from_to 1,'01/01/2016','21/12/2020'
```

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: (1) Don't store dates as strings... (2) Where does the error occur, at what line? (3) What is the region format of the server? (4) Do you think that, even if the conversion did work, `dd/mm/yyyy` format strings sort how you really want them to? See #1 again.

Comment: Don't use an ambiguous formats for your dates, and don't use a `varchar` for the data type. There is a `date` data type for a reason, and use a either `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnn` for your literal string dates.

Comment: I have tried in date, and datetime too

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Then the problem is also your database, and you are foolishly storing date and time data in a `varchar`. There is only one true solution; Fix your design.

Comment: Change the date format of the strings to yyyy-MM-dd to avoid ambiguity. For example, `exec emp_leave_from_to 1,'2016-01-01','2020-12-21' `.

Comment: Hello, dear SO colleagues:  With respect, let's remember that this isn't a code-review web site.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is here.

```
exec emp_leave_from_to 1,'01/01/2016','21/12/2020'
```

When you specify date constants, you need to give them as text strings in [ISO-8601 date format](http://exec%20emp_leave_from_to%201,%2701/01/2016%27,%2721/12/2020%27), like so.

```
exec emp_leave_from_to 1,'2016-01-01','2020-12-21'
```

This format is laid out as `YYYY-mm-dd`. It has the great benefit for internationally-distributed software that it avoids the ambiguity between `mm/dd/YYYY` and `dd/mm/YYYY` introduced by different date conventions in the US and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the date value you are passing into the stored procedure.

You are trying to pass in `'21/12/2020'`

SQL Server is trying to parse this into a date thinking it is formatted as `'MM/dd/yyyy'`, but you are passing in `'dd/MM/yyyy'`.

The best format to use is `'yyyy-MM-dd'`

Example, recreating your problem:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(date, '21/12/2020')
```

Returns:

```plaintext
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```